# Translations only load from `wp-content/languages/plugins` but not from the plugin's languages folder

Tags: plugin-development, translation, textdomain

I translated my plugin and put all the files (`my-plugin-de_DE_formal.po`, `my-plugin-de_DE_formal.mo`, `my-plugin.pot`) in the `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages` folder.

My plugins header says:

```
…
Text Domain: my-plugin
Domain Path: /languages
…
```

Inside my code I loaded the textdomain like that:

```
function mp__load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', false, 'my-plugin/languages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'mp__load_textdomain' );
```

I also check the return value of `load_plugin_textdomain` and it says `true`.

But all my translations will not show up. But if I move the `.po` and `.mo` files to the global folder `wp-content/languages/plugins` it works just fine.

I want to keep the translation file inside my plugin folder but I‘m stuck and can‘t figure out why it doesn‘t work that way.

**Edit:**

I came across that with the translation files located at  `wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages` all translations inside my custom post type's content work but all translations inside the cpt registration won't (and indeed I checked the right textdomain for typos etc).

Comment: `'my-plugin/languages'` is a relative path, are you sure you don't want an absolute path like the examples in the official documentation for `load_plugin_textdomain`?

Comment: I tried to use the absolute path `'/var/www/dev/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages'` but then `load_plugin_textdomain` returns `false` and fails. Using the relative path it returns `true` at least.

Comment: and you're sure it's not looking at `/languages` but `.... my-plugin/languages`?

Comment: `/languages` will not work either.

Comment: re: your last edit, the order things happen in matter. If you register your post type then load the language files, then your post type labels won't be translated because that happened before the language files were loaded. Also are you sure that you haven't tried the code suggested in the official docs? If so why have you reverted to the code used in your question instead? https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#loading-text-domain There should be a calls to figure out the path but yours just has the string `my-plugin/languages`

Comment: it also shouldn't be necessary to use `load_plugin_textdomain` if you've correctly specified the domain path in the plugin header. Is your text domain really `my-plugin`? It's hard to rule out common errors when the code shared has been highly censored and genericised, eliminating common errors in the process